# Tailwind SCSS with variables.scss

Tags: sass, tailwind-css

I am practising tailwind scss, and trying to create a theme similar to bootstrap. My current code for primary button, below which is working fine.

```
.btn-{
    &primary{
        @apply bg-blue-500 text-white;
        &:disabled{
            @apply bg-blue-500/50;
        }
    }
```

and my alert is

```
.alert-{
    &primary{
        @apply bg-blue-500 text-white;
    }
```

As bg-blue-500 is taken as primary color, i prefer to variable.scss file like

```
$bg-primary: @apply bg-blue-500; //throws error at scss
```

I dont want to hardcode the color, instead use the tailwind values. Is there a way to achieve this

Comment: You may change variable into `$bg-primary: theme('colors.blue.500')`. I personally prefer to go in opporiste direction - define color as CSS variable in SASS files like `--color-primary-500: #252A5B;` and within tailwind config define primary color 500 as `500: 'var(--color-primary-500)',`. This way I have more control as color may be referenced from backend. But it's depends on task of course

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was posted 10 months ago I gues this not urgent anymore but maybe this helps someone else:

For that purpose you can use the *theme* function provided by tailwind for that purpose:

`$myVar: theme(colors.blue.500)`

Resource: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives (at the very bottom)